# How to upload files from ruby client(its not a web client or a web form) to server (php handler) using http post?

Tags: php, ruby, file-upload, client-server, server

I want to upload files from ruby client(this is not a web form) to server(webhosting) [via a php backend file to store the files sent to server], need help in from where to start.

I have done the same using Java (using httpurlconnection). Need to know how it is done in ruby.

Awaiting a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "this is not a web form" mean? Does it mean you aren't POSTing the data to an endpoint the way a form would? It sounded like you need something along the lines of rsync, but then you said you used some tool called `httpurlconnection`, which makes it sound like its the same as a form submission, even if you're not filling in a form. Is it some other format? Some other method? You should specify, it's not relevant that the server is written in php, it is relevant how you talk to it, we don't know the interface.

Comment: I have a php script in server which handles the files uploaded from client (java for eg.) and saves it on to the server. For java client I used: "HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Upload_File.php");" and "MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();" and was able to send the files to server successfully.

Now the same I want to do using Ruby.